# Writing a simple web-based IDE - ideas / concepts?

Tags: ide

This may be a too broad question but how would you develop a simple web-based IDE/editor? For a lecture I was thinking of a simple editor where you could enter some sort of code, press compile and then display the results, error messages etc. in some way.

Does anyone knows some examples (with source code maybe), or any suggestions on how to do this conceptually?

Comment: Maybe have a look at Mozilla Bespin aka Skywriter (http://mozillalabs.com/skywriter/) or just use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could try http://codepad.org/

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in taking a look at the very new Eclipse Orion project, in particular the architecture overview: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Orion/Architecture

Answer (score 0):

[Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh) provides a framework for you to develop html5 applications with access to a real Ubuntu VM with Root. The idea for this post, being that you can develop an IDE that works with Client and Server languages, without having to deal with security of giving people access to machines that you are hosting. Security is hard with machines and avoiding exploits